# How to define XML URL path to a local file in jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer, path

I want to find a node in a XML which sits locally in my E drive. I am calling the below function to read the file but its giving me [object Object] error.

```
function getPetPrice(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "PetList.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) { alert("Sucess"); },
        error: function (errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); }
    });
}
```

I have tried to give the full path to the file but the issue remains the same. Please advise...

**UPDATE 1:**

The [object Object] is the XMLHttpRequest the first argument error functions received. I have changed my code to

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); }
```

Now the error its throwing is `Error: Invalid argument.`

Comment: Is the HTML with the script also loaded from the file system? Or do you expect a document loaded from a HTTP server to be able to load files from your file system?

Comment: Its a C# MVC project running on local IIS. The XML file is included in the project.

Comment: What happens when you load the URL (e.g. `http://localhost/someDir/PetList.xml`) directly in an IE window? Does IE render it?

Comment: Nopes. I get this `HTTP Error 404.8 - Not Found

The request filtering module is configured to deny a path in the URL that contains a hiddenSegment section.`